# PHP - Accessing Multidimensional Array Values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

After several hours of messing, sweating and pulling my hair out I'm still unable to access these values. I want to loop through the first level of arrays, and that's simple enough with a basic 'foreach' loop but I can't seem to get to the '['suitability']' array on the second sub array. I've looked around but can't seem to get anything other than really basic array tutorials which don't seem to delve to far into looping.

I'm trying to access the values in the nested/sub array ie '['Species_name']'.

I don't want to use associative keys as the sorting is a bit of an issue.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Bradeley Hall Pool
            [postcode] => CW1 5QN
            [lat] => 53.10213
            [lon] => -2.41069
            [size] => 1.60
            [pegs] => 21
            [distance] => 26.6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Farm Pool
            [postcode] => CW9 6JQ
            [lat] => 53.320502
            [lon] => -2.549049
            [size] => 0.88
            [pegs] => 8
            [distance] => 15.4
            [suitability] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fk_water_id] => 2
                            [fk_species_id] => 4
                            [species_name] => Barbel
                            [species_rating] => 1
                            [record_id] => 1
                            [weight_kg] => 2.721554
                            [length_cm] => 40
                            [height_cm] => 30
                        )
                )
       )
)
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "I don't want to use associative keys as the sorting is a bit of an issue."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for writing such a well written and detailed question! +1.

Answer (score 26):

The thing that is probably tripping you up is that suitability is an array of arrays not just an array so in an example where you want to get the species_name property of the first second top level element you would use something like

```
$array[1]["suitability"][0]["species_name"];
```

It's worth noting that your first array does not contain a "suitability" value so that would not be able to be accessed. In a foreach loop you could use a construct similar to this:

```
foreach($array as $value){
    if (isset($value["suitability"])){
        echo $value["suitability"][0]["species_name"];
    }
}
```

Comment: i just count array post inside then var_dump out side foreach, but it doesn't work, if you don't mind here is my script http://pastebin.com/jFxSkhzT

Comment: You are overwriting the variable $kuantity every iteration in the loop. What you are probably seeing is the value of the last iteration.

Comment: Change to `$kuantity[] = count($_POST['quantity'][$key]);`

Comment: it doesn't work, my format looks like in the above, here is reall format http://prnt.sc/cxq4gp

Answer (score 2):

For getting nested element value from multidimensional array (with optional fallback to default value) you can use [get method](https://minwork.gitbook.io/array/common-methods/get-getnestedelement) from [this array library](https://github.com/minwork/array):

```php
Arr::get($array, "$index1.suitability.$index2.species_name")

// Or using array of keys
Arr::get($array, [$index1, 'suitability', $index2, 'species_name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [PHP: RecursiveArrayIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

This allow you to iterate over multiples nested ArrayIterator. If you're not using any ArrayIterator, then you should consider to try them.

Answer (score 1):

Iracicot's answer helped me find my way towards accessing the values of a recursive array using the RecursiveIterator class as below. My solution ended up using the even more useful RecursiveIteratorIterator class as per http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php. Please bear in the mind the very useful fact that the end product is a flattened array which I personally found much easier to work with.

```
<table style="border:2px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Service Number</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
  </tr>
<?php 
foreach($stops as $buses){
       $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($buses));
       $bus = (iterator_to_array($iterator,true)); 
       print('<tr><td>'.$bus['AimedDepartureTime'].'</td><td>'.$bus['PublishedLineName'].'</td><td>'.$bus['DirectionName'].'</td></tr>');
}
?>
</table>
```