# PHP: How can I get the value from a key in a multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

The multiple array looks like

```
Array
(
    [id] => description
    [header] => 
    [width] => 20
    [dbfield] => description
    [type] => text
)
Array
(
    [id] => quantity
    [header] => Menge
    [dbfield] => QUANTITY_NEW
    [width] => 60
    [type] => decimal
)
```

How can I get the value from dbfield where id is 'quantity' without knowing the numeric value of the id?

The actual code looks like

```
foreach($array as $id => $fieldData) {

   if($fieldData['type'] == 'decimal') 
   {
     doSomething...();
   }
}
```

In the part with doSomething I need access to other fields from the array, but I only know the id. I already tried it with dbfield['quantity']['dbfield'] etc. which obviously fails.

Comment: Can you show any code attempts?  My first suggestion would be to think about how to derive a data structure against which you can perform the lookup you want. Beyond that, you should at least be able to cobble together a brute force approach and show you efforts here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Accessing Multidimensional Array Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with several methods, one of them is using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get those values:

```
$dbfield = array_filter(array_map(function($a){
    if($a["id"] === "quantity"){
        return $a["dbfield"];
    }
}, $array));

print_r($dbfield);
```

You iterate over the array, and return the key `dbfield` where `id` is 'quantity'. Array filter is just to not return null values where it doesn't have 'quantity' id.

Online attempt to reproduce your code can be found [here](http://ideone.com/fFU5ot)

Answer (score 1):

echo out the array as such..

```
$array = array();

$array['qty'] = 'qtty';
$array['dbfield'] = 'QUANTITY_NEW';

if($array['qty'] = 'qtty'){

echo $array['dbfield'];

} 

returns - QUANTITY_NEW
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative using `array_keys`:

```
function getValues($data, $lookForValue, $column)
{
    $res = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $data) 
    {
        if($idx = array_keys($data, $lookForValue))
        {
            $res[$idx[0]] = $data[$column];
        }
    } 

    return $res;
}

$values = getValues($myData, "quantity", "dbfield");

var_dump($values);
```