# Access Array Value Using Index Variable that contains brackets

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm having a simple issue that I've been beating my head against the screen trying to figure out.  I have a variable `$sceneArray` that holds the array listed below.  I also have another variable `$locateRecord` that holds something like `['opening']['scene2']`.

Ordinarily, to get the value of scene2, I would just reference `$sceneArray['opening']['scene2']`.  But in this case, I need to combine the two variables to retrieve that value.  I have tried things like `${sceneArray.$locateRecord}` but that isn't work for me either.

Would appreciate any hint!

EDIT: I have the ability to format the `$locateRecord` value in a different way if that can solve this.  For example, I could structure it as `opening>scene2` or `opening,scene2` etc.

```
Array
(
  [opening] => Array
    (
      [scene1] => 1:00
      [scene2] => 2:00
    )

  [closing] => Array
    (
      [scene3] => 3:00
      [scene4] => 4:00
    )
)
```

Comment: What do you get? Do you get an error? If you get an error can you please post it :D

Comment: There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003559/use-strings-to-access-potentially-large-multidimensional-arrays) questions [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466815/php-variable-variables-with-array-key) that deal with a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789932/get-value-from-array-using-string-php). That should get you started on the right path.

Comment: @NathanielEskenazi Thank you for the reply!  No error - just an empty value.

Comment: `eval` is the first thing that comes to mind. But there will be a bunch of people who don't like it. Can you afford, memory-wise, to build another data structure where `['opening---scene2']` is present?

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you for the links.  I've tried those approaches and, unfortunately, still not having any luck.