# How to access values inside multidimensional array php

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
     Array
(
    [TrackReply] => Array
        (


            [MoreData] => false
            [TrackDetails] => Array
                (
                    [Notification] => Array
                        (
                            [Severity] => SUCCESS
                            [Source] => trck
                            [Code] => 0
                            [Message] => Request was successfully processed.
                            [LocalizedMessage] => Request was successfully processed.
                        )

                    [TrackingNumber] => 123456789012
                    [TrackingNumberUniqueIdentifier] => 2457082000~123456789012~FX
                    [CarrierCode] => FDXE
                    [ServiceInfo] => FedEx International First
                    [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
                    [PackageSequenceNumber] => 0
                    [PackageCount] => 0
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2015-02-28T13:22:00+00:00
                    [DestinationAddress] => Array
                        (
                            [StateOrProvinceCode] => TN
                            [CountryCode] => US
                            [Residential] => false
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Getting this array from $response and from this array how can i get "Notification->Message" value, please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Accessing Multidimensional Array Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values)

Comment: There are many already asked similar Qs on Stack overflow 
[http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+access+values+inside+multidimensional](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=How+to+access+values+inside+multidimensional+array+php+-+Stack+Overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $array['TrackReply']['TrackDetails']['Notification']['Message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access using array

```
$arrayname['TrackReply']['TrackDetails']['Notification']['Message']
```