# PHP: Get single value from complex array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 150109 [format] => [safe_value] => 150109 ) ) )
```

I need to get the value "150109", but how on earth do I accomplish that?

Comment: `$data[0][0]["value"]` or `$data[0][0]["safe_value"]` if the `$data` is your array

Comment: did you try googling for an answer? You should be able to find [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values) on accessing multidimensional array values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top level:

```
print_r($data);
// Output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 150109 [format] => [safe_value] => 150109 ) ) )
```

Outmost element:

```
print_r($data[0]);
// Output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 150109 [format] => [safe_value] => 150109 ) )
```

Next level:

```
print_r($data[0][0]);
// Output: Array ( [value] => 150109 [format] => [safe_value] => 150109 )
```

The final value

```
echo $data[0][0]['value'];
// Output: 150109
```

Accessing each layer of values this way makes it easier to figure out how to get to your desired value. After a while this becomes more obvious.

Comment: Only the first one (top level) will actually output someting. So print_r($data); gives me: Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 150109 [format] => [safe_value] => 150109 ) ) ). This construction looks a bit different from my initial array.

Comment: @oivindr Then you have different data than in your example. However, to get the value in that array, you would do `$data['und'][0]['value']`.

Comment: Thank you! I need to clean up my code, but it looks like it's working. BTW, I got the first array constructin when I used: print_r(array_values($artnr)); Not sure why they differ.

Comment: It should not. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @oivindr Please click the `v` under the up/down-votes to this question to mark it as the correct solution. Indicating that this answer helped you makes it easier for people who may have a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get values of arrays continusly on multidimensional arrays:
`$value = $array[0][0]["value"];`