# Read array inside other array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to insert an array inside another array.

```
$int = array();
array_push($int, array('begin' => 0, 'end' => 10));
array_push($int, array('begin' => 10, 'end' => 20))
array_push($int, array('begin' => 30, 'end' => 30))
```

And I'm trying to read it:

```
foreach ($int as $sint) {
    echo $int->begin;
    echo $int->end;
}
```

But I receive:

> Trying to get property of non-object in

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is an array and you're trying to access as if it was an object. Instead of using `->`, try using `$int['begin']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Accessing Multidimensional Array Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `[]` to access to items in array. `->` is for accessing the object items.

In `foreach` loop single items are in `$sint`, not `$int`.

```
foreach ($int as $sint) {
   echo $sint['begin'];
   echo $sint['end'];
}
```