# How can I access multi-dimensional array with php?

Tags: php

My array is like this. So how can I access the names,values with php?

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => subject
        [value] => คอมพิวเตอร์ ม.3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => subject_code
        [value] => ง33101
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => subject_hour
        [value] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => semester
        [value] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => level
        [value] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => classroom
        [value] => 301
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => classroom
        [value] => 302
    )
)
```

I have tried FOREACH to loop through the array and it does the job, but how can I get their names and values to be used later?
My FOREACH code:

```
foreach($objects AS $values){
    foreach($values as $value){
        echo $value.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: access the key. `$value['name'];`

Comment: This is actually a bit misleading. What do you mean with `name`? The actual field with that name or the various keys being used?

Comment: It returns error if I use $values['name'] for example, when I use $values['subject'], an error is "Undefined index: subject in...".

Comment: Yes, I mean the keys and values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Accessing Multidimensional Array Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume your array is `$array`:

```
foreach($array as $item){
       $name = $item['name'];  //extract name
       $value = $item['value'];  //extract value
       echo $name.'  '.$value.'</br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index/key, just name it:

```
foreach($collection as $key => $value)
    print($key . ' = ' . $value . '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Iteration over $objects to get values and names;

```
foreach($objects as $value){
    echo "Name: ".$value['name'];
    echo " - Value: ".$value['value'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Add some details of what the code does, how it works. Code only answers are marked as not helpful. Always try to add some description of the code.