# Get a single item from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

I've seaching stack overflow and did not find what I`m trying to do ...
So here is the question:
**HOW TO RETURN STEAMID ONLY?**

CODE:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$steamID = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $steamID = test_input($_POST["steamID"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
$keyApp = '5DE00EE4D07BA728EDAB0B3C2961AA6B';
$api = "";
$json_data = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$keyApp&steamids=$steamID");
$array = json_decode($json_data, true);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["players"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(19) {
        ["steamid"]=>
        string(17) "76561198058543756"
        ["communityvisibilitystate"]=>
        int(3)
        ["profilestate"]=>
        int(1)
        ["personaname"]=>
        string(12) ""Cientistas""
        ["commentpermission"]=>
        int(1)
        ["profileurl"]=>
        string(37) "https://steamcommunity.com/id/rhatto/"
        ["avatar"]=>
        string(116) "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c9/c9442f1ea597a7685f8e50f2f7c922321beb4eba.jpg"
        ["avatarmedium"]=>
        string(123) "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c9/c9442f1ea597a7685f8e50f2f7c922321beb4eba_medium.jpg"
        ["avatarfull"]=>
        string(121) "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c9/c9442f1ea597a7685f8e50f2f7c922321beb4eba_full.jpg"
        ["avatarhash"]=>
        string(40) "c9442f1ea597a7685f8e50f2f7c922321beb4eba"
        ["lastlogoff"]=>
        int(1593317334)
        ["personastate"]=>
        int(0)
        ["realname"]=>
        string(44) "por erro em estudo sobre a hidroxicloroquina"
        ["primaryclanid"]=>
        string(18) "103582791454640235"
        ["timecreated"]=>
        int(1328817888)
        ["personastateflags"]=>
        int(0)
        ["loccountrycode"]=>
        string(2) "CN"
        ["locstatecode"]=>
        string(2) "32"
        ["loccityid"]=>
        int(9982)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i extract steamid from $array?
Already tryed this links
https://www.codewall.co.uk/how-to-read-json-file-using-php-examples/
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Comment: If there is only 1 id, `$array["response"]["players"][0]["steamid"]`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139453/php-accessing-multidimensional-array-values

Comment: Not sure if your value of `$keyApp` is important, or if this should have been removed from the code when you posted the question.

Comment: You must stop using the infernal function `test_input()`. This will cause you a lot of problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accessing the correct path to the `steamid` the only thing is, apparently you might have multiple items in the players array. So you'll probably need a loop of some sorts.

Something like this maybe:

```
$players = $array['response']['players'];

foreach($players as $player) {
  echo $player['steamid'] . '<br>';
}
```

Or if you always have 1 player in your players array you could also do this (quick and dirty):

```
echo $array['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$steamID = $array['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];`